# Redux: Best way to perform business logic with state data in event handlers

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I've spent a few weeks looking into this and see no consensus.  I have a component with event handlers.  They need to use state data unrelated to the component to perform business logic, and dispatch different actions based on that and component data.  What's the best way to do this?  I've listed some *very* simple examples that are not complete but show the gist of what I'm talking about.

### Method 1: Pass everything to the component

I can easily pass everything needed to the component, including state data not related to it.  The container doesn't need to extend React.Container.

```
MyContainer.js

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    foo: state.my.foo,
    bar: state.other.bar
  })
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  doSomething: (value) => {
    dispatch(someAction(value));
  }
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);


MyComponent.js

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler() {  
    if ( complicated logic with this.props.bar ) {
      this.props.doSomething(this.props.foo);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClickHandler} />
    )
  }
}
```

**PROS:**
Very simple.  Everything the component needs is passed into it.

**CONS:**
The component is doing business logic, and that doesn't seem right.  But I cannot easily perform this logic in the container because it doesn't easily have access to unrelated state data.

**ALTERNATIVE:**
I could pass through all those props into the component's doSomething(), and let the container's doSomething() perform the logic.  But this means some props are never used by the container, they're just passed through.  But this would put the business logic back into the container.

### Method 2: Make container extend React.Component and render the props it needs

I can define the container with a proper React.Component class, pass the state data it needs via props, define a function to use this state and local state data, and render it.

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler(foo) {
    if ( this.props.bar ) {
      this.props.dispatch(foo)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyComponent onClickHandler={this.onClickHandler} {...this.props} />
    )
  }
}
```

**PROS:**
Business logic can happen in the container.

**CONS:**
Lot's of ceremony.  The container must be passed whatever state data its business logic function needs.

### Method 3: Use mergeProps when exporting connect()

I haven't tried this.  But this third parameter to connect() exposes the resuults of mapState and mapDispatch, so you can generate functions that rely on mapState data.

I didn't even try this one as Dan Abramov implied it's not great, and could have a performance impact.

### Method 4: Use thunk and getSate()

Just pass whatever data the component needs.  Dispatch a function that uses getState() to look at state data needed for business logic.  It can then dispatch any final actions.

```
MyReducer.js

export function actionDecider(foo) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    if ( complicated logic with state.other.bar ) {
      dispatch(someAction(foo));
    }
  };
}


MyContainer.js

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    foo: state.my.foo
  })
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  doSomething: (value) => {
    dispatch(actionDecider(value));
  }
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  (dispatch) => ({
    ...mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
  })
)(MyComponent);


MyComponent.js

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler() {  
    this.props.doSomething(this.props.foo);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClickHandler} />
    )
  }
}
```

**PROS:**
Less code.  Very easy to grasp.  No need to stuff state data into weird areas, just access it when needed.

**CONS:**
Conflicting opinions on whether this is an anti-pattern.  Even Dan Abramov has expressed some opinions against it, although some say that's overblown.  Are there performance problems with huge state trees?

Personally, I like using thunk in Method 4.  Although I could see the alternative on Method 1 working too.  Is there a right way?  Is there a wrong way?

Comment: there is related topic http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/

Comment: Yep, I read through all of that before posting.  It suggests that thunks are fine to use.  But it's only one article in a sea of different opinions.  This seems like a common problem many projects hit at some point, so was hoping the community could help sort right vs wrong ways.

Comment: Well, I _am_ one of Redux's maintainers, so I'd like to think I have _some_ measure of credibility :)  (And yes, one of the opinions I argue against in that article is from Dan Abramov, the _creator_ of Redux, but this is one of the areas where I think he's sorta-kinda-wrong-ish).  You might want to read my other related article, [Idiomatic Redux: Why Use Action Creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).

Comment: Oh I had no idea you're one of the maintainers.  Sorry I didn't mean to downplay your opinion.  Knowing that you're a maintainer helps quite a bit.  My team has started undoing each others work because they've heard different things from different sources.  So having someone like yourself give feedback that business logic in thunks are ok is very helpful.  Much thanks!

Comment: Sure :)  FWIW, I also just wrote a pair of posts that discuss the history and intent behind Redux and why common practices exist, which you may find helpful and informative: [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/) and [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  Those posts are incredibly useful, and I really wish something like that existed when I first got started with React and Redux.  Does a great job at answering some of the whys of Redux.